# which type is best for three radiobuttons?

Tags: c#, radio-button, type-conversion

Maybe you consider this question trivial but im just curious what is your opinion.

I have three radiobuttons. "Show blue", "Show red" and "Show all".

I did it with nullable boolean. There is collumn in database where blue is 0 and red is 1 so in metode i have to translate bool to int to compare those values (i do it in c#).Of course it works, but i wonder if it is the best solution.

And question is wich type is best in this case? nullable bool, int, or maybe string?

Comment: Use an Enum. This is not at all what a bool is meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool` only has two possible values, true or false. If you need to represent more values you need to store it in some other way.

Using null value as the third value is an ugly code hack.

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29):

> a good way to remember what null means
>   is to remember that in terms of information, "lack of a value" is not
>   the same thing as "a value of zero"

That is, null is to be used when you do not have a value.

In your case, using an `enum` will be easier to read and understand and also you will be able to add more options later if that need arises.

```
enum MyTypes{
 blue = 1, 
 red = 2, 
 all = 3
}
```

In a database an `enum` becomes an int column containing the value of selected option.

Comment: And how to use it with radiobuttonfor?